Computing Tangential Derivative using the Dirichlet value
Let $\Gamma$ be a smooth boundary of a domain $\Omega$. Let $u = g$ on $\Gamma$. How can I compute the tangential derivative of the function $u$ using the information that $u = g$ on $\Gamma$? Please provide a reference.

You mean mathematically, or in actual practice? If the latter, how do you represent $g$?

As @WolfgangBangerth already mentioned, the practical implementation depends on the representation of $\mathbf g$. I will give a short answer for a polynomial curve.

Let $\Gamma\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ be a closed polygonal chain in 2D, with vertices $\mathbf{v}_1 = (x_1,y_1),\ldots,\mathbf{v}_n = (x_n,y_n)$ and let us have values defined at each vertex $g(\mathbf{v}_i) = g_i$. We will assume that $g:\Gamma\to\mathbb{R}$ is given
as a linear polynomial on each edge $\mathbf{v}_i, \mathbf{v}_{i+1}$
(the last edge is $\mathbf{v}_n,\mathbf{v}_0$). Then for $x\in [x_i,x_{i+1}]$ and $y\in [y_i,y_{i+1}]$ it has the form
\begin{equation}
g(x,y) = (1-\xi_i(x,y)) g_i + \xi_i(x,y) g_{i+1},
\end{equation}
where $\xi_i$ is defined as follows:
\begin{align}
\xi_i(x,y) &= \frac{(x-x_i, y-y_i)\cdot(\mathbf{v}_{i+1}-\mathbf{v}_i)}{\|\mathbf{v}_{i+1}-\mathbf{v}_i\|^2} 
\\
&=
\frac{(x-x_i)(x_{i+1}-x_i) + (y-y_i)(y_{i+1}-y_i)}{(x_{i+1}-x_i)^2 + (y_{i+1}-y_i)^2}.
\end{align}
The inverse of $\xi_i(x,y)$ gives the part of the curve $\boldsymbol{\gamma}$ on the edge $(x_i,y_i), (x_{i+1}, y_{i+1})$:
\begin{equation}
\boldsymbol{\gamma}_i(\xi_i) = \begin{bmatrix}
x(\xi_i) \\ y(\xi_i)
\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
(1-\xi_i) x_i + \xi_i x_{i+1} \\
(1-\xi_i) y_i + \xi_i y_{i+1}
\end{bmatrix}, \quad \xi \in [0,1].
\end{equation}
A full piecewise linear polynomial curve $\boldsymbol{\gamma} :[1,n+1) \to \Gamma$ can be assembled from the pieces:
\begin{equation}
\boldsymbol{\gamma}(\xi) = \begin{cases}
\gamma_1(\xi-1), &\text{for } \xi \in [1,2], \\
\vdots \\
\boldsymbol{\gamma}_i(\xi - i), &\text{for } \xi \in [i, i+1], \\
\vdots \\
\boldsymbol{\gamma}_n(\xi-n), &\text{for } \xi \in [n,n+1].
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
We can then define the function $g \circ \boldsymbol{\gamma} : [1,n+1) \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $g(i) = g_i$. The derivative is $\frac{g\circ \boldsymbol{\gamma}}{d\xi} = g_{i+1}-g_i$ for $\xi \in (i,i+1)$. This derivative, however, depends on the speed of the curve $\boldsymbol{\gamma}$. A possible canonical choice is to take the curve with constant unit speed. We can achieve this by arclength parametrizing $\boldsymbol{\gamma} \implies (\boldsymbol{\gamma} \circ \ell^{-1})$:
\begin{equation}
s = \ell(\xi) = \int_0^{\xi} \|\boldsymbol{\gamma}'(\zeta)\|_2 \,d\zeta 
\implies \frac{d\ell^{-1}}{ds}(\ell(\xi)) = \left(\frac{d\ell}{d\xi}(\xi)\right)^{-1} = \frac{1}{\|\boldsymbol{\gamma}'(\xi)\|_2}.
\end{equation}
Then the curve has constant speed $1$:
\begin{equation}
\left\|\frac{d\boldsymbol{\gamma}}{d\xi}(\xi)\right\|_2 = \|\boldsymbol{v}_{i+1}-\boldsymbol{v}_{i}\|_2, \,\, \xi \in (i,i+1); 
\quad 
\left\|\frac{d \boldsymbol{\gamma}\circ \ell^{-1}}{ds}\right\|_2 = 
\left\|\frac{d \boldsymbol{\gamma}}{d\xi}\right\|_2\left\|\frac{d\ell^{-1}}{ds}\right\|_2 = 1.
\end{equation}
For the derivative of $g\circ \boldsymbol{\gamma} \circ \ell^{-1}$ can be computed as follows:
\begin{equation}
\frac{g\circ \boldsymbol{\gamma} \circ \ell^{-1}}{ds}(s)=
\frac{g\circ \boldsymbol{\gamma}}{d\xi}(\ell^{-1}(s)) \frac{d\ell^{-1}}{ds}(s) = 
\frac{g_{i+1}-g_i}{\|\mathbf{v}_{i+1}-\mathbf{v}_i\|_2}, \quad \ell^{-1}(s) \in (i,i+1).
\end{equation}

If $\mathbf{g}$ are point values on a smooth curve $\boldsymbol s$ you can calculate the tangential derivative
$$ 
\begin{align}
\frac{ \mathrm{d} \mathbf g}{ \mathrm{d} s} =  \frac{1}{\|\boldsymbol{\gamma'}(\xi)\|_2}\circ \frac{ \mathrm{d} \mathbf g}{ \mathrm{d}  \xi}, \\
\end{align} 
$$
with
$$ 
\begin{align}
\|\boldsymbol{\gamma'}(\xi)\|_2 =  \sqrt{\left(\frac{ \mathrm{d} \mathbf{x}}{ \mathrm{d} \xi}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{ \mathrm{d} \mathbf y}{ \mathrm{d} \xi}\right)^2}, \\
\end{align} 
$$
and
$$ 
\begin{align}
\frac{ \mathrm{d} \mathbf x}{ \mathrm{d} \xi} =  \mathbf{\mathcal D}\mathbf x, \quad
\frac{ \mathrm{d} \mathbf y}{ \mathrm{d} \xi} =  \mathbf{\mathcal D}\mathbf y, \quad
\frac{ \mathrm{d} \mathbf g}{ \mathrm{d} \xi} =  \mathbf{\mathcal D}\mathbf g. \\
\end{align} 
$$
Here $\mathcal D$ is defined as derivative matrix, $\circ$ is the elementwise multiplication and $\mathbf x, \mathbf y$ are coordinates. The curve is parametrized using $\xi \in [0,1]$.  Note that $\mathbf x,\mathbf y, \mathbf g$ are nodal values
$$ 
\begin{align}
\mathbf x = \left(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n\right), \quad
\mathbf y = \left(y_1, y_2, \dots, y_n\right), \quad
\mathbf g = \left(g_1, g_2, \dots, g_n\right). \\
\end{align} 
$$
I agree with @lightxbulb that there is no unique solution for general boundaries $\Gamma$ of multidimensional manifolds, since there are infinitely many tangential directions.

Example: ($n=2$)
If $\boldsymbol s$ consists of many linear segments $s_i$, you can calculate the tangential derivative on each segment using
$$ 
\begin{align}
\frac{ \mathrm{d} \mathbf g}{ \mathrm{d} s_i} = \frac{ g_2 - g_1}{ \sqrt{\left(x_2 - x_1 \right)^2 + \left(y_2 - y_1 \right)^2}} . \\
\end{align} 
$$

Response to lightxbulb:
You do not need so much math to show the equations. Start with a simple line integral
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{\mathcal{C}} f(\boldsymbol{\gamma})\, \mathrm{d}s = \int_0^1 f\left(\mathbf{\boldsymbol{\gamma}}(\xi)\right) \| {\boldsymbol{\gamma}}'(\xi) \|_2 \,\mathrm{d} \xi,
\end{align}
$$
where $\xi\in [ 0,1]$. The relation does hold in arbitrary dimensions. Now skip $f(\boldsymbol{\gamma})$ to get the length of the curve
$$
\begin{align}
\mathcal{L}=\int_{\mathcal{C}}  \, \mathrm{d}s = \int_0^1  \| {\boldsymbol{\gamma}}'(\xi) \|_2 \,\mathrm{d} \xi.
\end{align}
$$
Without integrals you have
$$
\begin{align}
\mathrm{d}s =  \| {\boldsymbol{\gamma}}'(\xi) \|_2 \,\mathrm{d} \xi \quad \rightarrow \quad \frac{ds}{d\xi} = \| {\boldsymbol{\gamma}}'(\xi) \|_2.
\end{align}
$$
I assume, since we have a generalized 1D curve, we simply can apply the chain rule
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\mathrm{d} g}{\mathrm{d} s}&=\frac{\mathrm{d} g}{\mathrm{d} \xi}\cdot\frac{\mathrm{d} \xi}{\mathrm{d} s},\\
\frac{\mathrm{d} g}{\mathrm{d} s}&=\frac{\mathrm{d} g}{\mathrm{d} \xi}\cdot\frac{1}{\frac{\mathrm{d} s}{\mathrm{d} \xi}},\\
\frac{\mathrm{d} g}{\mathrm{d} s}&=\frac{\mathrm{d} g}{\mathrm{d} \xi}\cdot\frac{1}{\| {\boldsymbol{\gamma}}'(\xi) \|_2}. \quad\square
\end{align}
$$

Why are you dividing by the speed of the curve? Shouldn't the tangential derivative be just $J_{g \circ \varphi}(\varphi^{-1}(p))$ where $\varphi : \mathcal{D} \to \Gamma$, $\mathcal{D}\subseteq \mathbb{R}^{d-1}$, is a parametrization of the neighbourhood $\varphi(\mathcal{D})\subseteq \Gamma$ of $p$.

@lightxbulb The dot should indicate a spatial derivative in the reference domain. I admit this is a bit missleading. I will change that. Is that what you mean?

I wrote an answer that maybe clarifies what I mean. I did not understand why you took the derivative specifically w.r.t. a unit tangent vector. I suppose the notation $\frac{d\bm{g}}{d\Gamma}$ is referring to this, i.e., the derivative w.r.t. the unit tangent. I am not sure how this notation generalizes to higher dimensions, as there are infinitely many orthonormal bases that span the tangent space, so $\frac{dg}{d\Gamma}$ would not make sense there. Even in 1D $\frac{dg}{d\Gamma}$ is ambiguous since it could be positive or negative, but let's say it matches the orientation of $\Gamma$.

@lightxbulb Sorry for my late response, I was bussy with proper work. See my edit.

As defined above $s$ is a measure on $\Gamma$, namely $s(\mathcal{A}) = \int_{\mathcal{A}} ds= \int_{\gamma^{-1}(\mathcal{A})}|\gamma'(\xi)|_2,d\xi$ for $\mathcal{A}\subset \Gamma$ a measurable subset, so I do not get what $s\equiv\Gamma$ means. The notation $\frac{d\xi}{ds}$, or to be precise $\frac{d\lambda(\xi)}{ds}$ where $\lambda$ is the standard Lebesgue measure, is fine. On the other hand I don't know what $\frac{dg}{ds}$ is. $g$ is not a measure, so $\frac{dg}{ds}$ cannot be a Radon-Nikodym derivative. It's not a standard derivative either since $s$ is a measure. I am more confused.

I think I figured it out. I guess you define the function $s(\xi) = \int_{0}^{\xi} |\gamma'(\zeta)|_2,d\zeta$, and then $\frac{ds}{d\xi} = |\gamma'(\xi)|_2$ while $\frac{d\xi}{ds} = \frac{1}{|\gamma'(\xi)|_2}$ by the inverse function theorem. So $\frac{dg}{ds}$ is referring to a derivative wrt the arc-length parametrization, so the unit tangent derivative. I still don't get how $s\equiv \Gamma$, as the thing on the left measures length given a parameter, while the thing on the right is a manifold. An issue is that there is no arclength parametrization for e.g. $\Gamma$ a surface.

@lightxbulb With $\Gamma$ I did not want to indicate the boundary of an orientable manifold in physical space, but rather a onedimensional parameterized physical curve. This is actually
not clean. You are right that there are infinitely many tangent directions on a multidimensional boundary. I have limited myself here to the only unique case. I think we can agree that anything else doesn't make sense. In principle, $\frac{\mathrm{d}g}{\mathrm{d}s}$ simply indicates how $g$ changes when running along a onedimensional physical path $s$.

I will replace $\Gamma$ with $s$ with a note that there is no unique solution for general boundaries $\Gamma$. I appreciate your comments to make the answers better.

If you are fine with it I can try to edit your answer, and you can decide whether to keep the edits. There are some confounding details like: $s$ being called a smooth curve when it is a parametrization,  $g$ being treated as $g\circ \gamma$, the usage of $ds$ as a measure in the edit, also the statement about the "unique solution". To be sure, the derivative is unique, it is just that there is no canonical choice of basis/coordinates in higher dimensions (unlike for a curve where you have chosen the arclength to be canonical).

@lightxbulb Sure, I have nothing against it.

I added something, if you don't like it I will move it to my answer. While writing it I realized that $\frac{d\mathbf{g}}{d\xi}$, $\frac{d\mathbf{x}}{d\xi}$, and $\frac{d\mathbf{y}}{d\xi}$ in your answer also do not make sense, since you defined $\mathbf{g} = (g_1,\ldots,g_n)$ which is a vector and not a function, and similarly for $\mathbf{x}$, $\mathbf{y}$. As noted, calling $\mathbf{s}$ a curve is also wrong, as the arc-length parametrized curve is $\boldsymbol{\gamma}\circ \ell^{-1}(s)$, or $\boldsymbol{\gamma} \circ \xi^{-1}(s)$ if you prefer.

I am not quite sure, if you have fully understand what i wanted to express with my answer. I admit, that I demanded too much implicit  knowledge from the readers. Moreover, the nomenclature may not fully be accurate from a mathematical point of view. However, the vectors $\mathbf{g,~x,~y}$ were chosen deliberately. Each vector should represent a polynomial of degree $n-1$, where each entry in the vector is to be understood as a nodal point of a Lagrange polynomial.

The derivative matrix in the linear case is $\mathcal{D}=
\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & +1 \
+1 & -1
\end{bmatrix}
$, however is different for higher order polynomials. I am currently not quite sure about your math. It seems to complicated for me. The relation of the line integral and the simple chain rule seems sufficient for me. For example I do not understand, why you write
$ \frac{g~\circ ~\gamma~\circ ~l^{-1}}{\mathrm{d} s}$ instead of $\frac{\mathrm{d} g}{\mathrm{d} s}$. I think we should rather discuss this in a chat, if you want.

Let's try a chat: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/154199/tangential-derivative

I am currently bussy. I let you when I am free.

I have to write $\frac{g\circ \gamma \circ \ell^{-1}}{ds}$ because the latter is a function of $s$. $g:\Gamma\to\mathbb{R}$ is not a function of $s$, it takes as an argument a point from $\Gamma$. Similarly $g \circ \mathbf{\gamma} : [0,n+1) \to \mathbb{R}$ is not a function of $s$ either. These are all different functions. A bigger issue is notation like $\frac{d\mathbf{g}}{d\xi}$ where $\mathbf{g}$ is now a vector, and not a function. At the very least one must define what the notation means and why that would be equal to the tangential derivative. This is not standard notation afaik.

I tried to provide an answer just as much for myself, since I could not understand where some of the terms in @ConvexHull's answer come from. I can't quite tell what $\newcommand{\bm}[1]{\boldsymbol{#1}}\frac{d\bm{g}}{d\Gamma}$ is supposed to be, but from the derivation I did below it seems like they are computing the coordinates of the unit tangent derivative.

Derivative and Gradient in Local Coordinates
Let $\partial\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^m$ be a continuously differentiable $n$-dimensional manifold embedded in $\mathbb{R}^m$. Suppose we are given a parametrization $\bm{\varphi}:D\subset\mathbb{R}^n\to U\subseteq\partial\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^m$ . The tangent space $T_p\partial\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^m$ at $\bm{\varphi(\bm{t})}=\bm{p}\in U \subset \mathbb{R}^m$ has a basis
given by the columns of the Jacobian:
\begin{equation}
\bm{J}_{\bm{\varphi}}(\bm{t}) = \begin{bmatrix}
| & & | \\
\frac{\partial\bm{\varphi}}{\partial t^1}(\bm{t}) & \ldots & \frac{\partial \bm{\varphi}}{\partial t^n}(\bm{t}) \\
| & & |
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix} 
\frac{\partial \varphi^1}{\partial t^1}(\bm{t}) & \ldots & \frac{\partial \varphi^1}{\partial t^{n}}(\bm{t})
\\
\vdots & & \vdots 
\\
\frac{\partial \varphi^m}{\partial t^1}(\bm{t}) & \ldots & \frac{\partial \varphi^m}{\partial t^{n}}(\bm{t})
\end{bmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}.
\end{equation}
The cotangent space $(T_p\partial\Omega)^* \subset (\mathbb{R}^m)^*$ has a dual basis spanned by the rows of any generalized inverse $(\bm{J}_{\bm{\varphi}}(\bm{t}))^{-}$, since if we have the SVD $\bm{J}_{\bm{\varphi}}(\bm{t}) = \bm{U} \begin{bmatrix} \bm{\Sigma}_{11} \\ \bm{0}\end{bmatrix} \bm{V}^T$, it follows that:
\begin{equation}
(\bm{J}_{\bm{\varphi}}(\bm{t}))^{-} = \bm{V} \begin{bmatrix} \bm{\Sigma}_{11}^{-1} & \bm{X} \end{bmatrix} \bm{U}^T \implies 
(\bm{J}_{\bm{\varphi}}(\bm{t}))^{-}\bm{J}_{\bm{\varphi}}(\bm{t}) = \bm{I}_n.
\end{equation}
Now let $f:\partial\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$, the derivative $df(\bm{p}): T_p\partial\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ is from $(T_p\partial\Omega)^*$, while the gradient is from $T_p\partial\Omega$ and satisfies $\langle \bm{\nabla} f(\bm{p}), \bm{v}\rangle = df(\bm{p})(\bm{v})$. We can compute the derivative $df(\bm{\varphi}(\bm{t}))$ in the basis $\bm{J}_{\bm{\varphi}}(\bm{t})$ as follows:
\begin{equation}
d (f\circ \bm{\varphi})(\bm{t}) = \bm{J}_{f\circ\bm{\varphi}}(\bm{t})\bigl(\bm{J}_{\bm{\varphi}}(\bm{t})\bigr)^{-}, \quad 
\bm{J}_{f\circ\bm{\varphi}}(\bm{t}) = \textrm{coordinates of the derivative}.
\end{equation}
We can use the standard inner product from $\mathbb{R}^m$, then the inner product for the coordinates on the basis $\bm{J}_{\bm{\varphi}}(\bm{t})$ is given as
\begin{equation}
\langle \bm{J}_{\bm{\varphi}}(\bm{t})\bm{x}, \bm{J}_{\bm{\varphi}}(\bm{t})\bm{y}\rangle_{\mathbb{R}^m} = \bm{x}^{T}\bm{G}\bm{y} = 
\langle \bm{x}, \bm{y}\rangle_{\bm{G}}, \quad \bm{G} = (\bm{J}_{\bm{\varphi}}(\bm{t}))^T\bm{J}_{\bm{\varphi}}(\bm{t}).
\end{equation}
Then using $d(f\circ \bm{\varphi})(\bm{t})(\bm{x}) = \langle \bm{\nabla} (f\circ\bm{\varphi})(\bm{t}),\bm{x}\rangle_{\bm{G}}$ the gradient can be computed as follows:
\begin{equation}
\bm{\nabla}(f\circ\bm{\varphi})(\bm{t}) = \bm{J}_{\bm{\varphi}}(\bm{t})\bm{G}^{-1}\bigl(\bm{J}_{f\circ\bm{\varphi}}(\bm{t})\bigr)^T, \quad 
\bm{G}^{-1}\bigl(\bm{J}_{f\circ\bm{\varphi}}(\bm{t})\bigr)^T = 
\textrm{coordinates of the gradient}.
\end{equation}

Extension of $f$ from $\partial\Omega$ to $\Omega$
If $f$ is defined on a neighbourhood around $\partial\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^m$ then $\bm{J}_f(\bm{p})\in\mathbb{R}^{1\times m}$ is well defined, and we can write:
\begin{equation}
\bm{J}_{f\circ\bm{\varphi}}(\bm{t}) = \bm{J}_f(\bm{\varphi}(t))\bm{J}_{\bm{\varphi}}(\bm{t}) \in\mathbb{R}^{1\times n}.
\end{equation}
This is what happens for $u:\Omega \to \mathbb{R}$, we can treat $u$ as the extension of $g$ from $\partial\Omega$ to $\Omega$. So it holds:
\begin{equation}
\bm{J}_{g\circ \bm{\varphi}}(\bm{t}) = \bm{J}_{u\circ \bm{\varphi}}(\bm{t}) = \bm{J}_{u}(\bm{\varphi}(\bm{t}))\bm{J}_{\bm{\varphi}}(\bm{t}).
\end{equation}
Though I don't think this is as useful in practice, since I suppose one wants the derivative in terms of the known data, and not in terms of the unknown solution.

2D Example
Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^2$, and $\partial\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ be a piecewise linear closed polygon with vertices $\bm{v}_1,\ldots,\bm{v}_k$. We can parametrize an arbitrary edge as $\bm{\varphi}(t) = (1-t)\bm{v}_j + t\bm{v}_{j+1}$ (if $j+1=k+1$ we set $j+1$ to be $1$ instead). Define $g\circ\bm{\varphi}$ to be an affine function: $(g\circ\bm{\varphi})(t) = (1-t)g_j + tg_{j+1}$. The Jacobian of $g\circ\bm{\varphi}$ is just the derivative w.r.t. $t$: $J_{g\circ\varphi}(t) = \frac{d(g\circ\bm{\varphi})}{dt}(t) = g_{j+1}-g_j$. As a covector from $(\mathbb{R}^2)^*$ this takes the form
\begin{equation}
d(g\circ \bm{\varphi})(t) = (g_{j+1}-g_j) (\bm{J}_{\bm{\varphi}}(t))^{-} = 
(g_{j+1}-g_j)\frac{(\bm{v}_{j+1}-\bm{v}_j)^T}{\|\bm{v}_{j+1}-\bm{v}_j\|^2_2},
\end{equation}
where I have chosen the Moore-Penrose inverse, and the computations then become:
\begin{equation}
\bm{J}_{\bm{\varphi}}(t) = \frac{d\bm{\varphi}}{dt}(t) = \bm{v}_{j+1}-\bm{v}_j \implies 
(\bm{J}_{\bm{\varphi}}(t))^+ = \bigl((\bm{v}_{j+1}-\bm{v}_j)^{T}(\bm{v}_{j+1}-\bm{v}_j)\bigr)^{-1}(\bm{v}_{j+1}-\bm{v}_j)^T.
\end{equation}
The gradient is then just the transposed of this:
\begin{equation}
\bm{\nabla} (g\circ\bm{\varphi})(s) = (g_{j+1}-g_j)\frac{\bm{v}_{j+1}-\bm{v}_j}{\|\bm{v}_{j+1}-\bm{v}_j\|^2_2}.
\end{equation}

ConvexHull's Answer
I think ConvexHull assumed an arc-length parametrization:
\begin{align}
\bm{\gamma}(t) = \bm{v}_j + s\frac{\bm{v}_{j+1}-\bm{v}_{j}}{\|\bm{v}_{j+1}-\bm{v}_j\|_2}, \quad
 (g\circ\bm{\gamma})(s) = g_j + s\frac{g_{j+1}-g_{j}}{\|\bm{v}_{j+1}-\bm{v}_j\|_2},
\end{align}
which leads to the derivative w.r.t. the unit tangent $\frac{\bm{v}_{j+1}-\bm{v}_j}{\|\bm{v}_{j+1}-\bm{v}_j\|_2}$:
\begin{equation}
\frac{d(g\circ \bm{\gamma})}{ds}(s) = \frac{g_{j+1}-g_j}{\|\bm{v}_{j+1}-\bm{v}_j\|_2}.
\end{equation}
Granted, if we have that $\frac{d\bm{\varphi}}{dt}(t)$ is not unit length, we can always normalize in order to get the coordinates of the derivative w.r.t. a unit tangent vector. I am not sure why this was done. This can also be generalized to boundaries of higher dimensions: we can take the columns of $\bm{J}_{\bm{\varphi}}(\bm{t})$ and we can orthonormalize those, and then rewrite the coordinates w.r.t. the new orthonormal basis. On the other hand such an assignment is not unique, while the notation $\frac{dg}{d\Gamma}$ suggests that this ought to be independent of parametrization. The object that is truly independent of parametrization is rather the differential $dg(p):T_p\Gamma \to \mathbb{R}$.

Thank you, @WolfgangBangerth and  @ConvexHull. This question arises when solving a biharmonic equation with clamped boundary conditions. We are given u and normal derivative of u on the boundary. Now, I want to compute the gradient of u on the boundary. To that end, I need tangential derivative of u on the boundary. g is given as a smooth function.

You're not supposed to use answers to ask new questions. If you have $\partial_n u(\partial\Omega) = f(\partial\Omega)$ and $u(\partial\Omega) = g(\partial\Omega)$ and you are in 2D then $n^T\nabla u = \partial_n u = f$ and $t^T\nabla u = \partial_t u = \partial_t g$ then $$\nabla u = \begin{bmatrix} n^T \ t^T\end{bmatrix}^{-1}\begin{bmatrix}f \ \partial_t g \end{bmatrix}.$$ Here $t$ is a tangent, and $n$ a normal. If they are orthonormal then the inverse matrix is just the transpose.
